Is it possible to run javascript to generate a license number that will be sent with a completed woocommerce order?
I wish to create a license number generator, for a product sold on my Wordpress site, that is identical to the one in my Filemaker (standalone/unserved) database.
The only language common to both web and FM is Javascript.
I created an FM script that scrapes my FM solution's webviewer for the license number created after a client enters their name.
All efforts to create a matching process on my website - that sends a license number to a client when they complete an order - have failed.
Is is possible to generate a license number using Javascript; then, incorporate the result in a Woocommerce order completed email?
I've tried various methods to generate a license number, and dispatch it on completion of a Woocommerce order.
A PHP translation of my FM code, added to my website's function.php, file 'worked' (i.e. a license number was generated and sent via email), but it failed to produce a license number that matched either the FM or Javascript ones created within FM.
Efforts to have Javascript create the license number and PHP run the code and email - either via my website's function.php file, a pair of code snippets, or a DIY plugin - did nothing at all, and nor could I work out what the problem was because no debug file could be generated.
Here is a PHP snippet used to call the Javascript:
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_js');

function enqueue_custom_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-reg-code-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'reg-code.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('custom-reg-code-js', 'customData', array(
        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    ));
}

add_action('wp_ajax_custom_send_email', 'custom_send_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_send_email', 'custom_send_email');

function custom_send_email() {
    $regName = sanitize_text_field($_POST['regName']);
    $users = intval($_POST['users']);
    $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
    $regCode = sanitize_text_field($_POST['regCode']);

    error_log("Received AJAX: RegName - $regName, Users - $users, Email - $email, RegCode - $regCode");

    if (empty($regCode) || empty($email)) {
        error_log("Registration code or email is empty.");
        wp_send_json_error('Registration code or email is empty.');
        return;
    }

    $email_sent = send_registration_email($email, $regName, $regCode);
    if ($email_sent) {
        error_log("Email sent successfully.");
        wp_send_json_success('Email sent successfully.');
    } else {
        error_log("Failed to send email.");
        wp_send_json_error('Failed to send email.');
    }
}

function send_registration_email($to, $name, $registration_code) {
    $subject = 'Your Registration Code New';
    $message = "<html><body><h2>Thank you for your purchase!</h2><p>Dear {$name},</p><p>Your registration code is: <strong>{$registration_code}</strong></p><p>Please use this code to activate your new software.</p><p>If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact our support team.</p><p>Best regards,<br>Your Company Name</p></body></html>";
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    return wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

And here is the Javascript it should 'call':
function generateRegistrationCode(regName, users) {
    const solutionKey = 'tcuXd6A4WQ';
    
    if (!regName || !solutionKey) {
        console.error('Registration name or solution key is empty.');
        return '';
    }

    // Always append users (which is set to 1)
    regName += users;

    let len = regName.length;
    let chr = 0, pos = 0;

    for (let loop = 0; loop < len; loop++) {
        const ascii = regName.charCodeAt(loop);
        chr += ascii;
        pos += (ascii * (loop + 1));
    }

    const sum = chr + pos + len;
    const numString = `${sum}${pos}${chr}${len}${sum * sum}`;
    let codePreFormatted = '';

    let loop = 0;
    while (loop < numString.length) {
        const convertNum = (parseInt(numString.substr(loop, 2)) > 56) ? parseInt(numString.substr(loop, 1)) : parseInt(numString.substr(loop, 2));
        codePreFormatted += (convertNum == 0) ? solutionKey[0] + solutionKey[1] : solutionKey[convertNum];
        loop += convertNum.toString().length;
    }

    let codeFormatted = '';
    for (let loop = 0; loop < codePreFormatted.length; loop += 4) {
        if (codeFormatted) codeFormatted += '-';
        codeFormatted += codePreFormatted.substr(loop, 4);
    }

    // Append users (always 1) to the final code
    codeFormatted += `-[${users}]`;

    console.log(`Generated registration code: ${codeFormatted}`);

    // Append the registration code to the checkout page
    document.getElementById('registration-code-display').innerText = codeFormatted || 'Registration code generation failed.';
    
    return codeFormatted;
}

// Send registration code via AJAX
function sendRegistrationCode(email, regName, users) {
    const regCode = generateRegistrationCode(regName, users);

    if (!regCode) {
        alert("Registration code generation failed. Please check the input.");
        console.error("Failed to generate registration code.");
        return;
    }

    // Perform AJAX request to send the email
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: customData.ajaxUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'custom_send_email',
            regName: regName,
            users: users,
            email: email,
            regCode: regCode,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                alert('Registration code sent successfully!');
            } else {
                alert('Failed to send the registration code: ' + response.data);
                console.error('Failed to send the registration code:', response.data);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
            console.error('AJAX error:', error);
        }
    });
}

Note that in my JavaScript code "users" variable argument is not required and will be removed (as there is always one user at the time).
Also note that actually orders get completed automatically, once customer submits a successful payment.
But, if I translate my license number generation sequence algorithm into PHP, the license number sent in a separate email, doesn't match the one created in Filemaker.

Are the license numbers close? What steps have you taken to debug each? I would walk through the license number creation in each app, step-by-step to determine where they differ.

I don't think the php calling the JS is relevant, as long as it's passing the correct arguments. Which version is correct, if any? Is there a way to only use one of the methods to generate it? Can you retrieve the number from the database to send?

Why shouldn't tht be possible? But keep in mind that generating license numbers in JS makes your generation visible to all users. That could lead to the situation that everybody could generate their own license number without actually paying for it

You should only use the closest server-side algorithm to generate your serial numbers, for security reasons (here using PHP and custom database table(s)), as your FMP application is standalone/unserved.

I'd like to thank everyone for taking the time to respond to my request.

Thanks for the Javascript security issue comments. I'll stick to PHP.

The closest license key match I've managed so far, on username "Han Solo", users=1, and solution key:  "tcuXd6A4WQTrPL19YkiwNBnxv87MEgDqpfJF52jU3aCSysHzbGKRVZehm" is: FM: "H4xW-Qt44-UBWM-6W-[1]" and PHP:  "H4xW-Q444-UBWM-6Wd-[1]"

I've been unable to trace the cause of the mismatch. The FM script includes steps such as "set variable $ASCII; Value: Code(Middle ( $RegName ; $loop ; 1 ))"  which, of course, can't be quoted verbatim in PHP (the nearest match I could come up with was "$ascii = ord(substr($reg_name, $loop, 1))). I concluded that - much like spoken language - it is impossible to match two computer languages exactly.

If you need help with anything, please add all clarification to your question by editing it
